# How do I add data from a model to a model with the same field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
public class UserTBModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

}

public class UserViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How do I add data from a model to a model with the same field?

how to UserViewModel = UserTBModel ?

I want to put the data of the table, which is the output type of the first model, into the second model and return it

Comment: That's not something you can do out of the box. Have a look at [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html), that might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a constructor that takes UserTBModel as parameter:

```
 public class UserViewModel {
    public UserViewModel(UserTBModel userTBModel) {
        this.ID = userTBModel.ID;
        this.Name = userTBModel.Name;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

And then:

```
var userViewModel = new UserViewModel(userTBModel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no inheritance relationship between the two classes, it's not something you can do out-of-the-box. You need to use refelection to solve it, and luckily there are several mappers that do that for you. One of them is [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html).
Install AutoMapper and do this:

```cs
UserTBModel userTBModel;
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<UserTBModel, UserViewModel>());
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
UserViewModel model = mapper.Map<UserViewModel>(userTBModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use implicit/explicit operators,

```
public class UserViewModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public static implicit operator UserViewModel(UserTBModel userTBModel){
       return new UserViewModel{
                 ID = userTBModel.ID,
                 Name = userTBModel.Name
       };
   }
 }
//example of use
UserViewModel userViewModel = userTBModel;
```

or

```
public class UserViewModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public static explicit operator UserViewModel(UserTBModel userTBModel){
        return new UserViewModel{
               ID = userTBModel.ID,
               Name = userTBModel.Name
              };
    }
 }
//example of use
UserViewModel userViewModel = userTBModel as UserViewModel;
```